# Riddle:you see all your friends when you're with me. but when you come to me, you look at your own face the most

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Riddle: you see all your friends when you're with me. but when you come to me, you look at your own face the most
The answer belongs to a non-living thing and commonly seen in houses and offices.

Answer (score 4):

Guess it is:

> Facebook

cause:

> All your friends are there, and you can see your own wall.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is:

> goggles

because:

> When you wear them, you see everybody. But when you look at them, all you see is your mirrored face on glass.